# is it possible to fix a broken gpio pin?

Tags: gpio

my 5V and 3.3V pins are not supplying any current, so I'm assuming that the pi is broken, is is there any way to fix it, do normal computer stores fix this, or should it be immediately replaced?

Comment: As advised in your duplicate if the 5V pin **which is not a GPIO pin** is not working your power supply is broken (unless you have totally fried the Pi).

Comment: You haven't even told us what model Pi or why you think it is broken or how it is powered.

Answer (score 1):

There is no known  cost effective repair. It will be cheaper to buy a new Pi.